# LINQ Query to find where in collection on an included table

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am having trouble writing the statement to return a list of results where the joined (included) table matches a collection of item.

I am using EF 5.0 entity model. I have a simple `VendorProfile` table with a PK/FK table of `VendorCategories` they have selected that can be joined on `ProfileID`.

I cannot figure out how to get only the results back where the VendorProfiles  have VendorCategories that matches a collection (passed in from a form post).  I was attempting to build a dynamic search function that can handle multiple search criteria, which all works but the first one where I need to filter results where there is a collection of `criteria.categories`.

```
public class CustomSearchCriteria
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public DateTime? startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? endDate { get; set; }
    public int[] categories { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<VendorProfile> Search(CustomSearchCriteria criteria)
{
    IQueryable<VendorProfile> query = _db.VendorProfiles
        .Include("VendorCategories")
        .OrderBy(v => v.ProfileID);

    if (criteria.categories != null)
        query = query.Where(v => v.VendorCategories.Contains(criteria.categories));

    if (criteria.name != string.Empty)
        query = query.Where(v => v.Name.Contains(criteria.name));

    if (criteria.company != string.Empty)
        query = query.Where(v => v.CompanyName.Contains(criteria.company));

    if (criteria.startDate != null && criteria.endDate != null)
        query = query.Where(v => v.DateCreated > criteria.startDate && v.DateCreated < criteria.endDate);

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: What is the condition for filtering? Are you looking for `VendorProfile` which has all `VendorCategories` specified by `criteria` or at least one `VendorCategory` specified by `criteria`?

Comment: Based on the code snippet, and the verbiage above, I would say that OP's intent is to find a `VendorProfile` which has all of the specified criteria categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the following using [Queryable.All()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534754.aspx), and let me know how it works:

EDIT #1: Changed the query to match up the variable types, under the assumption that `criteria.categories` contains a collection of VendorCategoryIDs.

Edit #2: Changed the query to use Any() instead of All(), per the comments

```
query = query.Where(v => criteria.categories.AsQueryable().Any(cat => v.VendorCategories.Select(vendCat => vendCat.VendorCategoryID).Contains(cat));
```

Comment: syntax is not correct (best overload has some invalid arguments), but researching this option more. Thx

Comment: Edited to fix that problem.

Comment: Thx. This query does work but is performing an && operation instead of || operation. Meaning if I check multiple categories I only get those vendors that match all selections and not vendors that match any. This might work, but I would like to know how to make it go the other way too. Is that possible?

Comment: Thx again!  I hope this helps others with similar problem.

Comment: new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536154/entity-framework-linq-return-column-based-on-record-in-fk-table)

Answer (score 0):

```
// assumes v.VendorCategories is int[]
if (criteria.categories != null && criteria.categories.Any())
    query = query.Where(v => v.VendorCategories.All(id => criteria.categories.Contains(id)));
```

Comment: This only returns those whose vendor categories are contained in the criteria list. If criteria.categories has anything extra in it, this profile record won't get filtered out.

Comment: So you are looking to have a match if any VendorCategory is listed as any one of the criteria.categories?  If so, you can the "VendorCategories.All" to "VendorCategories.Any"

Comment: No. I assumed that OP was trying to get all VendorProfile records where each element of the `criteria.categories` array was found in that record's VendorCategories collection.

Comment: @IronMan84 your solution was so helpful, I even included a radio button option so the user could search matching all or matching any. I was hoping you could might comment on next challenge to make all the form values retain their value after postback.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224850/retaining-form-values-after-post-not-part-of-model)