# Return column based on record in FK table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a success query for displaying Vendors, but what I wanted to add now is a column showing which vendors have been selected or not (displayed as a checkbox column). These selections are stored in VendorsSelected table that contains the FK ProfileID and UserName that selected them. So when the current user views the Vendors there will be matches for some Vendors and not for others.

How do I modify the query?  Note the Where clause below will accomplish getting only vendors that the current user has selected, but what I want is all vendors displayed with true/false (checkbox) column for each vendor they have selected.

```
public IEnumerable<BrowseVendorModel> BrowseVendors()
{
    IQueryable<BrowseVendorModel> viewModel = _db.VendorProfiles
        .Include("VendorsSelected")
        .Select(s => new BrowseVendorModel
        {
            ProfileID = s.ProfileID,
            Name = s.Name,
            CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
            City = s.City,
            State = s.State,
            DateCreated = s.DateCreated
        })
        .Where(x => x.VendorsSelected.Select(s => s.UserName).Contains(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
        .OrderBy(v => v.ProfileID);

    return viewModel;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property `Selected` (`boolean`) to the view model:

```
public IEnumerable<BrowseVendorModel> BrowseVendors()
{
    IQueryable<BrowseVendorModel> viewModel = _db.VendorProfiles
        .Include("VendorsSelected")
        .Select(s => new BrowseVendorModel
        {
            ProfileID = s.ProfileID,
            Name = s.Name,
            CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
            City = s.City,
            State = s.State,
            DateCreated = s.DateCreated,
            Selected = x.VendorsSelected.Select(s => s.UserName)
                        .Contains(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
        })
        .OrderBy(v => v.ProfileID);

    return viewModel;
}
```

Comment: OMG I didn't know you could do that. I have spent years writting SQL but having to relearn doing it the LINQ way. Where do I go to learn to be a LINQ ninja like you? :)  Thx

Comment: Just keep on doing it I guess :)

Comment: Posted another LINQ Ninja [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671371/linq-to-entities-selecting-one-bool-column-from-another-table) modification of the above query.

Comment: I posted another [LINQ problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047420/linq-to-ef-working-with-lookup-tables) that went unanswered, hoping you can help.